# Side effects of setting mutable-content

Tags: apple-push-notifications

[apns docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification) says:

> `mutable-content` The notification service app extension flag. If the value is 1, the system passes the notification to your notification service app extension before delivery. Use your extension to modify the notification’s content. See Modifying Content in Newly Delivered Notifications.

Is there any side affect of this if the device does not have a notification service app extension?

Comment: If your app did not register an extension (like when user has an older version of the app), `mutable-content` is effectively ignored by iOS.